# Запрос логина и пароля C# + PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, postgresql, npgsql

Хочу сделать форму авторизации в приложении. Есть 2 textBox и кнопка войти. По нажатию на кнопку войти происходит запрос в бд по наличию введенных данных. Но в моём коде блок if выполняется независимо от того, чтобы я не вводил в текстбоксы. Застрял надолго на этом моменте. Может кто-то подсказать, в какую сторону копать ? Я только начинаю работать с базами данных и слегка запутался.

```
var login = authWindows.loginBox.Text;
var pass = authWindows.passBox.Text;
long rowsCount = 0;

using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=123456"))
{
    connection.Open();              
    NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM admin.users WHERE login = @login AND pass = @pass", connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@login", NpgsqlDbType.Text).Value = login;
    command.Parameters.Add("@pass", NpgsqlDbType.Text).Value = pass;            
    rowsCount = (long)command.ExecuteScalar();
    if (rowsCount > 0)
    {
        authWindows.Close();
        workSozWindow.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Пользователь не найден");
    }
}
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145110/discussion-on-question-by-nedjad-----c-postgresql); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Проблема была в этих строках:

```
authWindows authw = new authWindows();

string login = authw.loginBox.Text.Trim();
string password = authw.passBox.Text.Trim();
```

Я получается создавал новую невидимую форму и вследствии чего поля ввода были пустыми. В итоге я избавился от переменной authw и передал login и password в виде параметров в метод authWithDb и всё заработало.

Всем спасибо за помощь!